# The minimax function does not seem to be outputting the correct evaluation for the board

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm using Python to create a unbeatable TicTacToe game with the MiniMax Algorithm. My code does not seem to outputting the correct evaluation for each position. From what I understand, the alogorithm should "test" each position by assuming that the human player plays optimally. However, the evaluation always returns  a NoneType.

I tried using other numbers in the evaluation function with an else. However, doing that does not seem to return the correct evaluation, or at least, I think it's not correct.

```py
board= ["O", 1, "X", 
        "X", 4, "X", 
        6, "O", "O"]

human = "O"
robot= "X"


#winning board combinations
def winning(board, player):
        #horizontal tests
    if((board[0] == player and board[1]==player and board[2]==player) or
        (board[3]==player and board[4]==player and board[5]==player) or
        (board[6]==player and board[7]==player and board[8]==player) or
        #diagonal tests
        (board[0]==player and board[4]==player and board[8]==player) or
        (board[2]==player and board[4]==player and board[6]==player) or
        #vertical tests
        (board[0]==player and board[3]==player and board[6]==player) or
        (board[1]==player and board[4]==player and board[7]==player) or
        (board[2]==player and board[5]==player and board[8]==player)
        ):
        return True
    else:
        return False


#evaluates the score of the game
def evaluation(board):
    if (winning(board, human)):
        return +10
    elif (winning(board, robot)):
        return -10
    elif(len(empty_spots)==0):
        return 0
    #trying to get another value
    # else:
        # return 2


#this is to find the empty spots on the board 
def empty_spots_func(board):
    for i in board:
        if(i!="X" and i!="O"):
            empty_spots.append(i)


def minimax(spot, empty_spots, depth, maximizing_player):
    if depth<=0:
        eval= evaluation(board)
        print(f'The evaluation function returns: {evaluation(board)}')
        return eval

    if maximizing_player:
        maxEval= -1000000
        #for each move in all possible moves
        for spot in empty_spots:

            #make the move
            board[spot]=robot

            #evaluate the outcome of the move
            eval = minimax(spot, empty_spots, depth-1, False)

            #then remove the move and replace it with the number
            board[spot]=spot

            maxEval= max(maxEval, eval)

        # print(f'The maximum evaluation {maxEval}')
        return maxEval

    else:
        minEval= +1000000
        #for each move in all possible moves
        for spot in empty_spots:

            #make the move 
            board[spot]=human

            #evaluate the outcome of the move
            eval= minimax(spot, empty_spots, depth-1, True)

            #then remove the spot
            board[spot]=spot

            #figure out the minimal evaluation
            minEval=min(minEval, eval)

        # print(f'The minimal evaluation is {minEval}')
        return minEval
```

And now testing for one position in the main function:

```
    test_spot_eval=minimax(0, empty_spots, len(empty_spots), True)
    empty_spots_func(board)
    print(f'The spot eval is {test_spot_eval}')
```

Without the last "else" in evaluation, minimax just returns a NoneType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a separate program to check the evaluation and the winning combinations. It turns out, the errors I was making was:

1. I was not placing the human input on the board, after taking in the user input
2. I had not noticed that I incorrectly made the evaluation function return a positive value for the human win and a negative value for the robot win when it should have been the other way around.

There might be more mistakes I have not noticed yet.

Error 1 was causing my evaluation function to return a NoneType because, without the human input, the algorithm could not evaluate a winning position.